Как в DAX сделать матрицу от календаря и подсчитать выручку по дате продажи?

есть таблица (ниже), которая связана [дата_заявки]-> [календарь дат].
есть на дашборде таблица (матрица), где первая колонка [дата_заявки].

Как сделать меру, которая в новую колонку матрицы выведет сумму продажи по дате продажи?
+----+-------------+--------------+---------+
| id | дата_заявки | дата_продажи | выручка |
+----+-------------+--------------+---------+
| 1  | 2024-11-10  | 2024-12-10   | 10000   |
+----+-------------+--------------+---------+
| 2  | 2024-10-10  | 2024-11-10   | 20000   |

